# What is the xml equivalent of this bean configuration where an object is being passed for which there is no bean configuration defined?

Tags: java, spring

I need to add OAuth client to a Spring 3 project. I need to use xml based configuration. And I want to know the xml equivalent of the following bean configuration I found in another Spring project. Note that there is an input parameter in the bean definition where an object of type OAuth2ClientContext is being passed (OAuth2ClientContext is an Interface) and is named clientContext. But no bean definition is written anywhere for clientContext. What does this mean? And how would you write this in xml?

```
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext){
     return new OAuth2RestTemplate(oauth2Resource(), clientContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration should be like this

```
<bean id="client" class="package.OAuth2ClientContext" />
<bean id="resource" class="package.Oauth2Resource" />
<bean id="restTemplate" class="package.Oauth2Resource">
    <property name="nameOfPropertyResource" ref="resource" />
    <property name="nameOfPropertyClient" ref="client" />
</bean>
```

are you sure that the bean client is not declared? Maybe it’s declared in some jar? If yes you should find it’s name and use the name in the ref